# Forwarding comments from a channel to a private message (Telebot)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

The function `bot.send_message()` sends posts to the telegram channel , users leave comments under these posts.
Problem with send all comments back to the user's personal chat with the bot and so that the user himself can respond in comments via the telegram bot. **Chat ID** and **management group ID** (which contains all posts and comments to them, the link to which is in the format: *****?thread =34**, where 34 is the number of the post, and *** is the ID of the message with a comment) do not match, therefore the **message IDs are also different** (for example, in the chat the post ID = 22, in the group the ID of the same post = 34). Comments in **manage group reply** to message with post that send.
How, when initially sending a post via private messages from a telegram bot, can you link to the comments section and receive their ID in a logical form and how can you get/ contact / download all comments under a certain post (?thread=34)

I don't understand which IDs (what logic of this ID) need to be entered in function `bot.send_message()` and `bot.forward_message()`